# I want to make my prime number range finder program faster in C

Tags: c

im kinda new to programming ,and i have that exercise.I made a program that runs just right for small ranges of numbers,but for this exercise we are given a high range of nums,and it just takes much time to finish examining.
Any suggestions how can i make it faster?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define START 190000000 
#define END 200000000

int main()
{
    int primenum = 0, i = 0, j = 0, c = 0;
    for (i = START; i <= END; i++)
    {
        printf("EXMINING %d\r\n", i);
        c = 2;
        for (j = 2; j <= i-1; j++)
        {
            if (i%j == 0)
            { c=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (c == 2) primenum = primenum + 1;
        printf("Prime Numbers Found so far: %d\r\n", primenum);
    }
    printf("THE PRIME NUMBERS ARE %d", primenum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow) on [meta]. [The answer by Joe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261966/14122) is a particularly effective summary.

Comment: You don't set `c` to anything other than `2`.  It's not clear why you use `\r\n`.  And you test a load of even numbers which is fairly pointless.  After you check 2, you don't need to test any more even numbers.  After testing 2 and 3, you can test 6*n±1 (for n = 1, test 5 and 7).  This reduces the number of tests even more.  You can also stop testing when `j * j > i-1` — this saves a lot of tests (for example, for i = 97, it saves testing from 8 through 96 — and the saving is bigger on bigger prime numbers).  Also, you recompute the primes each time; you'd do better computing them once.

Comment: There are numerous questions about prime number finding here on SO, and even without going for Sieve of Atkins, using Sieve of Eratosthenes is a valuable step in the right direction.

Comment: your code is not calculating primes at least not printing them to the screen

Comment: thank u very much @JonathanLeffler , could u please explain why i should use j*j > i-1?i cant seem to get it

Comment: If a number, C, is a composite number, then for any two factors such that C = A * B, one of A or B is less than or equal to √C and the other is greater than or equal to √C.  So, to check whether a number N is prime, it is sufficient to check whether prime numbers from 2 to √N are divisors; if the number is composite, you will have found a factor, and if you've not found a factor by then, it is prime.  Beware to branch the right way on equality; √25 = 5 and you need to test whether 5 is a factor to know whether 25 is prime or not.  (And I mistyped — I meant continuing while `j * j <= i`).

Comment: Since this is working code, this question is perhaps off-topic on SO, and should be for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), by my understanding of SO, being new here.

Comment: You might find some of the code available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub (for example, file `isprime.c` in the [Primes](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/Primes) sub-directory) of use.  Your code corresponds to the example that I have to special case (`IsPrime0()`)  because it is so abysmally slow.  Any of the others will be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if i is odd. If is even (except 2) is not a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your inner loop with this,

```
   for(j=2;j<=sqrt(i);j++)
```